# With testthat, where to place a custom skip function?

Tags: r, testthat

Where to place this function:

```
skip_on_any <- function() {
  skip_on_cran()
  skip_on_travis()
  skip_on_appveyor()
  skip_on_bioc()
}
```

So that I can use it within any of my test files.

Comment: Have you looked at the [R Packages book](https://r-pkgs.org/tests.html)? The chapter on testing looks like it might help

Comment: Not sure how that helps... but I tried placing it in `tests/testthat.R` but it is not read, so when I use it within my expectations it is not found. I am also not sure if it makes sense to make it a function of my package because it is just a helper fn for testing..

Comment: I was looking mostly at the bits there on organization and refactoring tests (in your case, that would be skips more than expectations). There are also helper files mentioned [in the docs](https://testthat.r-lib.org/reference/test_dir.html#test-files) but not addressed in the book chapter